# Periodic extrapolation out of the domain of the solution of a PDE in two directions

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions, periodic-function

As a prototypic problem

```
reg = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];
eqn = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 1;
bc = {
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]
   };
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] reg, Method -> {"FiniteElement"}]
```

code above runs normally. But the result obtained `sol` as an `InterpolatingFunction` is only defined within `reg`, e.g., `sol[2, 2]` issues a reasonable "InterpolatingFunction::femdmval" error message. Also, the obtained `InterpolatingFunction` has shown some properties like "Domain: {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}", "Output: scalar" and "Order: 2", etc.. Especially, there is one "Periodic: False".

This visualizes the result

```
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

So this makes me can't help asking that is it possible to make modifications to above code to make `sol` a periodic function, e.g., by using `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` (which I have tried but I was not able to make it work)?

Were that implemented, the above hump should forms a square lattice and `sol[2, 2]` should have the value of `sol[0, 0]`.

Comment: I'm afraid the question itself is wrong, or at least the problem doesn't have a solution in classical sense. It's easy to show that you can't make $u$  and derivative of $u$ be periodic and continuous at the same time.

Comment: The wording of the title is missleading : The word "condition" let think that you mean "boundary condition of the PDE". Apparently, you simply want to extrapolate the domain of sol from [-1,1][-1,1] with a periodic extrapolation (it implies that the derivative can't be continuous at the boundaries)

Comment: @andre314 Sorry for that. If possible, please help correct the title with more appropriate terms, thank you!

Comment: Done ! - Hope there no other problem

Answer (score 4):

> sol a periodic function, e.g.

I am not sure I understood the question, so I do not know if this is what you mean. If not, will be happy to delete it. Hard to show this in comment.

```
reg = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];
eqn = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 1;
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]};
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] reg, Method -> {"FiniteElement"}]
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, PlotRange -> All,  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To make the solution "periodic"

```
solPeriodic[x_, y_] := Module[{x0 = x, y0 = y},
   If[x > 1, x0 = x - 2];
   If[x < -1, x0 = x + 2];
   If[y > 1, y0 = y - 2];
   If[y < -1, y0 = y + 2];
   If[Abs[x0] > 1 || Abs[y0] > 1, solPeriodic[x0, y0], sol[x0, y0]]
   ];
```

Check:

```
solPeriodic[2, 2]
(*0.294685*)
sol[0, 0]
(*0.294685*)

Plot3D[solPeriodic[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot3D[solPeriodic[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, this is the desired result. But is it possible to implement it in the process of PED solution?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I do not know how to do the above directly by chnaging BC in the NDSolve call itself, and not sure if it is possible now. May be someone will have an idea.